# How to Avoid non printable characters in excel using Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am using attached code to convert .XLSX files into .CSV files. It is working fine except in one scenario. The code cannot handle non-printable excel characters. If it finds any such characters in excel it's creating one extra row in CSV file. I cannot tell what character it is because it's not visible in excel and it's disappearing when I apply the excel `Clean()` formula.

How can I handle this in Java?

Thanks
Madhu.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class XlsxtoCSV {

        static void xlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
                // For storing data into CSV files

            //System.out.println("Calling ::::::::::::::::::: method");
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                        // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
               XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

                        // Get first sheet from the workbook
                        XSSFSheet sheet = wBook.getSheetAt(0);
                        Row row;
                        Cell cell = null;
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                                row = rowIterator.next();

                                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                                        cell = cellIterator.next();



                                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                                data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");

                                                break;
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                                data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");

                                                break;
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                                                String st=cell.getStringCellValue();
                                                if(st.contains("\"")) {
                                                    st=st.replaceAll("\"", "");
                                                }
                                                if(st.contains(",")) {
                                                    st="\"" + st + "\"";

                                                }

                                                if(st.contains("\n")) {
                                                    st=st.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                                                }


                                                data.append(st + ",");
                                                break;

                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                                data.append("" + ",");

                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                data.append(cell + ",");

                                        }
                                }
                                data.append("\n");


                        }

                       fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
                       fos.close();

                } catch (Exception ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(ioe);
                }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            File inputFile = new File("D:/test.xlsx");
            File outputFile = new File("D:/test.csv");
                xlsx(inputFile, outputFile);
        }
}
```

Comment: You are probably getting a \r character which you should also replace with a space.